# Wait for a parent state to change in an onClick Event React using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-redux, react-hooks

The problem I am facing is the following.

I have a React stateless dropdown component which has exposed an onClick method.

When this onClick method is triggered I change the dropdown state which is again passed to the same dropdown component.

The dropdown component is as follows:

```
<DynamicDropdown
    dropdown={dropdownData}
    state={dropdownState}
    onToggleClick={onDropdownToggleClick}
    onDismissDropdown={onDismissDropdown}
/>
```

Currently the onDropdownToggleClick method is as follows:

```
const [dropdownState, setDropdownState] = useState<DropdownState>();
const onDropdownToggleClick = async (s: DropdownState) => {
  if (s === 'closed') {
    setDropdownState('fetching');
    const requests = await EnvironmentsAPI.getEnvironmentActiveRequests(
      environmentId
    );
    setActiveRequests(requests);
    setDropdownState('open');
  } else {
    setDropdownState('closed');
  }
};
```

Now I have a requirement that I have one state `fetching` coming from the redux store in my React component. This fetches some data every 15seconds and is a boolean value.

Now the requirement is that when the dropdown is toggled (onDropdownToggleClick) and `fetching` is `true`, I have to set my dropdownState as 'fetching' and wait for it to become `false`. When it becomes false then only I have to execute the statement

```
const requests = await EnvironmentsAPI.getEnvironmentActiveRequests(
  environmentId
);
```

Now the problem is that fetching is handled by redux and it does not gives a promise which I can await.

I tried doing 2 things:

1 -

```
const onDropdownToggleClick = async (s: DropdownState) => {
  setEnvironmentToggled(true);
  if (fetching) {
    setDropdownState('fetching');
  } else {
    if (s === 'closed') {
      setDropdownState('fetching');
      const requests = await EnvironmentsAPI.getEnvironmentActiveRequests(
        environmentId
      );
      setActiveRequests(requests);
      setDropdownState('open');
    } else {
      setDropdownState('closed');
    }
  }
};
```

and then there is a useEffect in which I open the dropdown like

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!fetching) {
    setDropdownState('open');
  }
},[]);
```

But the problem here is fetching is being polled every 15 seconds and most of the time it is false. Every 15 seconds it is changed to true for 1 second at max. So most of the times my dropdown becomes 'open' even if the API to fetch environments is not complete.

2 - I try to manually create a promise somehow which will resolve when fetching changes. This promise will only be created when dropdown is toggled.

```
const [fetchingResolve, setFetchingResolve] = useState<
  (value?: unknown) => void
>();
useEffect(() => {
  if (!fetching && fetchingResolve) {
    fetchingResolve();
  }
}, [fetching, fetchingResolve]);
const onDropdownToggleClick = async (s: DropdownState) => {
  if (s === 'closed') {
    setDropdownState('fetching');
    const fetchingPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
      setFetchingResolve(resolve);
    });
    await fetchingPromise;
    const requests = await EnvironmentsAPI.getEnvironmentActiveRequests(
      environmentId
    );
    setActiveRequests(requests);
    setDropdownState('open');
  } else {
    setDropdownState('closed');
  }
};
```

Now this promise is getting resolved immediately. I tried keeping this promise in useRef.

```
const fetchingResolve = useRef<(value?: unknown) => void>();
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(fetchingResolve.current);
  if (!fetching && fetchingResolve.current) {
    fetchingResolve.current();
  }
}, [fetching, fetchingResolve.current]);
const onDropdownToggleClick = async (s: DropdownState) => {
  if (s === 'closed') {
    setDropdownState('fetching');
    const fetchingPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
      fetchingResolve.current = resolve;
    });
    await fetchingPromise;
    const requests = await EnvironmentsAPI.getEnvironmentActiveRequests(
      environmentId
    );
    setActiveRequests(requests);
    setDropdownState('open');
  } else {
    setDropdownState('closed');
  }
};
```

This worked partially. The problem with this was if the `fetchingResolve.current` is undefined initally then it will wait for the next cycle of fetching(15 seconds) before updating.

Any leads or another approach will be very helpful. Thanks.

Let me know if I am not able to explain my problem.

Comment: Can you describe your goal as a user story?

Comment: @PavlosKaralis I did not understand. Can you clarify?